# How to rotate table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to rotate left table to right:

[image]

And left table is very long, about 1000 lines. The problem is to name columns in the right table automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to have about 1000 columns?  Are you trying to change the presentation or the table structure?

Comment: Yes, I want to have 1000 columns in right table.

Comment: No, he is counting the **goods** elements in the right table...

Comment: Interesting problem... I have seen a solution for this but can't remember where. Don't know why anyone would vote you down, its actually a cool problem to solve.

Comment: @Ziyao Wei This is just a simple example only. The question is about how to rotate table in Oracle.

Comment: @AJC Maybe you could find that solution? :-)

Comment: who voted him down? it is a legitimate requirement. It is called pivoting a table.

Comment: @kmb385 I need to create the second (right) table, from the source first (left) table...

Comment: take a look at my answer below. The technique is to go through all of the rows in your original row and create columns depending on the value and then combine them later using group by and sum.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Oracle 11g, there is a pivot query feature.  I have not used it yet, but it looks like something like this is what you need:

```
select * from (
   select bill, goods
   from bills
)
pivot 
(
   count(goods)
   for goods in ('TV', 'CD', 'phone', 'mouse')
)
order by bill
```

It seems to require that you list the possible values for `goods`.  But if you need to generate this on the fly, you could do one query to get the distinct values, turn that list into a comma-delimited string, and then execute the real query as dynamic SQL or a generated script.

(I would expect there to be a table listing the possible values of `goods`, which you could use to generate the list of values instead of querying the large fact table.)

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this

```
select bill, sum(p.TV), sum(p.CD)
  from (select bill, decode(goods,'TV',1,0) as TV, decode(goods,'CD',1,0) as CD
          from original_table) p
  group by bill
```

more info here: http://orafaq.com/node/1871

Comment: Isn't there a `PIVOT` function in oracle?

Comment: @Hyangelo O, thank you. But it is a real problem to name 1000 rows like that. I would like to give columns names also in script. Is it possible?

Comment: its not really about the number of rows but the number of values possible for your goods column. Do you have 1000 kinds of goods?

Comment: Yes there is a pivot operator(as of 11g i think) but it works the same way as my example. see: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/PivotAndUnpivotOperators_11gR1.php

Comment: Yes, I have more then 1000 kinds of goods. It's marketing task. I prepare table for basket analysis.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to automatically enumerate the columns. You could use a code generator to generate your script. It won't be that hard since it will be just decode(goods,'VALUE',1,0) as VALUE. Not sure if that is a good idea though

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but you would need to hardcode the values. You could write a script to produce the sql for you.

```
SELECT
SUM(bill) AS bill
SUM(CASE goods WHEN ‘TV’ THEN bill ELSE 0 END) AS TV,
SUM(CASE goods WHEN ‘CD’ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CD,
-- 998 more like this
FROM
tab
GROUP BY goods;
```

*UPDATE*
You can use a plsql script to build the sql for you, or you can modify it to build a view for you. You can run the script to update the view when values change.

```
DECLARE
  query_str VARCHAR;
BEGIN

select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TAB';

query_str := 'SELECT SUM(bill) AS bill,';

for col in (select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TAB') loop
  query_str := query_str || SUM(CASE goods WHEN ‘'' || col.column_name || ''’ THEN bill ELSE 0 END) AS ' ||  col.column_name || ', '
end loop;

query_str := query_str || ' FROM tab GROUP BY goods;';

dbms_output.put_line(query_str);

END;
```

Comment: Thank you. But in my task hand code is not possible, because I have very much goods and I need to change them some times.